# Facebook login fails in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, authentication

In my app I have to load a web page in UIWebView where user can login with Facebook. The problem is that when user clicks login, blank page appears.

Is it possible to get back to first page and be logged in?

Web page works perfectly in Safari and opens new window and after login it closes it and gets back to where it left.

EDIT: wrong URL was provided to UIWebView

Comment: Hi! How did you solve this? I'm currently facing the same exact problem and none of the solutions on SO haven't worked for me so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the sample of facebook SDK for iOS does the log in way you want.
Please refer to the link: 
facebook-iOS-SDK-sample: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook

Especially this part in https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/sample/Hackbook/Hackbook/RootViewController.m

```
/**
 * Show the authorization dialog.
 */
- (void)login {
    HackbookAppDelegate *delegate = (HackbookAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (![[delegate facebook] isSessionValid]) {
        [[delegate facebook] authorize:permissions];
    } else {
        [self showLoggedIn];
    }
}
```

When you click on log in button, it will open a login dialog, and ask for permission. This is what it looks like: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/screenshots/ios/#iphone-native

I think the best way to implement the "facebook-related" app is to start with the Hacbook. It is really a nice and detailed sample.

Comment: The login button is in web view, i cant control this part. It has to be in web view.

Comment: at that point, yes, but it was so long time ago that I'm not sure if it has any relevance now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reload a specific url after the facebook login popup is closed to prevent being stuck on a blank page you can use this code.

First include the UIWebViewDelegate and set your delegate somewhere in your code.

```
[yourwebView setDelegate:self];
```

Then use the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method to check request url for close_popup.php which is used by Facebook to close their popup.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{    
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", request];
    if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"close_popup.php"].location == NSNotFound) {
        //The close_pop.php is not found. (Do nothing)
    } else {
        //Facebook closed the popup so we should load the page we now want the user to see. 
        NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.ca/thepageyouwanttoreload.html"];
        NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SSL issue?  As per Joanne use the facebook SDK and you get loads of extra functionality for free, including logging in via the facebook native app if its installed.